# Python gtk3 treeview right click not select the correct selection

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I have the following code and when I select a row directly with the right button its outputs the previous selected item, not the current one just clicked.

What I am missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, Gio

class Test(Gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
    store = Gtk.ListStore(str)
    self.tree = Gtk.TreeView(store)
    for i in range(0,10):
        store.append(["test " + str(i)])
    self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    self.tree.connect("button_press_event", self.mouse_click)

    renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Title", renderer, text=0)
    self.tree.append_column(column)
    self.add(self.tree)

def mouse_click(self, tv, event):
    if event.button == 3:
        selection = self.tree.get_selection()
        (model, iter) = selection.get_selected()
        print(model[iter][0])

win = Test()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I tried your example code, and actually works, but you first you need to select the item and *then* right click to get the actually string.. I think becuase when you right click you'll get the last selection before the new one , you might want to try [get_cursor](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-cursor)  instead

Comment: I reckon your signal handler is running before the widget's own `button-press-event` handler, so it runs before the selection is changed. I want to say use `connect_after()` instead, but there has to be a better way, considering it's relatively common for a program to want to open a context menu on a tree row (which is what a button 3 handler would do)...

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `treeview.get_path_at_pos(x, y)`, using the coordinates sent with the button press event. Once you have a path, you have all you need to go further.

Here is a fully working example, note the extra lines in `mouse_click()`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, Gio

class Test(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        store = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.tree = Gtk.TreeView(store)
        for i in range(0,10):
            store.append(["test " + str(i)])
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.tree.connect("button_press_event", self.mouse_click)

        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Title", renderer, text=0)
        self.tree.append_column(column)
        self.add(self.tree)

    def mouse_click(self, tv, event):
        if event.button == 3:
            # Begin added code
            pthinfo = self.tree.get_path_at_pos(event.x, event.y)
            if pthinfo != None:
                path,col,cellx,celly = pthinfo
                self.tree.grab_focus()
                self.tree.set_cursor(path,col,0)
            # End added code

            selection = self.tree.get_selection()
            (model, iter) = selection.get_selected()
            print(model[iter][0])

win = Test()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from a vala project where I have implemented the above logic from @Kristof, just in case it is useful to someone.

```
//add mouse click listener
            device_table_treeview.button_press_event.connect ((widget, event) => {
                //capture which mouse button
                uint mouseButtonClicked;
                event.get_button(out mouseButtonClicked);
                //handle right button click for context menu
                if (event.get_event_type ()  == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS  &&  mouseButtonClicked == 3){
                    debug("Show Context Menu");
                    //determine the position on which the right click has happened          
                    TreePath path; TreeViewColumn column; int cell_x; int cell_y;
                    device_table_treeview.get_path_at_pos ((int)event.x, (int)event.y, out path, out column, out cell_x, out cell_y);
                    device_table_treeview.grab_focus();
                    device_table_treeview.set_cursor(path,column,false);
                    //get details of the selected row and display the context menu
                    TreeSelection aTreeSelection = device_table_treeview.get_selection ();
                    if(aTreeSelection.count_selected_rows() == 1){
                        TreeModel model;
                        TreeIter iter;
                        aTreeSelection.get_selected (out model, out iter);
                        deviceContextMenu(model, iter);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            });
```

The full code can be found here on GitHub:
https://github.com/babluboy/nutty/blob/master/src/devices.vala

Answer (score 0):

Use "button_release_event" rather than "button_press_event" to ensure that a clicked row is selected before any further action is taken.

```
self.tree.connect("button_release_event", self.mouse_click)
```